# Multivariate Emission Hidden Markov Model in STAN

Tags: hidden-markov-models, wavelet, stan, pystan

I'm trying to implement a HMM where the observations are the emissions from a first order HMM convolved with a wavelet.

That is:

[image]

With:

[image]

and

[image]

The code I have so far is, following along with the one dimensional case outlined [here](https://zenodo.org/record/1284341/files/main_pdf.pdf):

```
%%writefile HMM_code.stan
data {
int<lower=1> T; // number of observations (length)
int<lower=1> K; // number of hidden states
int<lower=1> H; // number of elements in wavelet vector
vector[K] dir_alpha;
real y[T]; // observations
matrix[T,H] W; // Wavelet matrix
cov_matrix[H] I; //prior covariance
}

parameters {
    // Discrete state model
    simplex[K] pi1; // initial state probabilities
    simplex[K] A[K]; // transition probabilities
    // A[i][j] = p(z_t = j | z_{t-1} = i)
    // Continuous observation model
    vector[H] Mu[K]; // observation means
    real<lower=0> sigma; // observation standard deviations
    cov_matrix[H] Sigma[K]; 
    vector[T] eei[H]; // 
}

transformed parameters {
    vector[K] logalpha[T];
    { // Forward algorithm log p(z_t = j | y_{1:t})
        real accumulator[K];
        logalpha[1] = log(pi1) + multi_normal_lpdf(eei[1] | Mu[][1], Sigma[][1]);
        for (t in 2:T) {
            for (j in 1:K) { // j = current (t)
                for (i in 1:K) { // i = previous (t-1)
                    // Murphy (2012) p. 609 eq. 17.48
                    // belief state + transition prob + local evidence at t
                    accumulator[i] = logalpha[t-1, i] + log(A[i, j]) + multi_normal_lpdf(eei[t] | Mu[][j], Sigma[][i]);
                }
                logalpha[t, j] = log_sum_exp(accumulator);
            }
        }
    } // Forward
}

model{
    Mu ~ multi_normal(rep_vector(0.0,H),I);
    sigma ~ inv_gamma(.1,.1);
    for(k in 1:K)
        A[k] ~ dirichlet(dir_alpha);
    for( j in 1:K)
        Sigma[j] ~ inv_wishart(3.0, I); //Relevant part for this post

    for (t in 1:T)
        y[t] ~ normal(W[t,]*eei[t], pow(sigma,.5));// Likelihood 
}

generated quantities {
    vector[K] alpha[T];
    vector[K] beta[T];
    vector[K] gamma[T];
    vector[K] loggamma[T];
    int<lower=1, upper=K> zstar[T];
    { // Forward algortihm
    for (t in 1:T)
        alpha[t] = softmax(logalpha[t]);
    } // Forward
    { // Backward algorithm log p(eei_{t+1:T} | z_t = j)
        real accumulator[K];
        vector[K] logbeta[T];
        for (j in 1:K)
            logbeta[T, j] = 1;
        for (tforward in 0:(T-2)) {
            int t;
            t = T - tforward;
            for (j in 1:K) { // j = previous (t-1)
                for (i in 1:K) { // i = next (t)
                    // Murphy (2012) Eq. 17.58
                    // backwards t + transition prob + local evidence at t
                    accumulator[i] = logbeta[t, i] + log(A[j, i]) + multi_normal_lpdf(eei[t] | Mu[][i], Sigma[][i]);
                }
                logbeta[t-1, j] = log_sum_exp(accumulator);
            }
        }
        for (t in 1:T)
            beta[t] = softmax(logbeta[t]);
    } // Backward
    { // forward-backward algorithm log p(z_t = j | eei_{1:T})
    for(t in 1:T) {
        loggamma[t] = alpha[t] .* beta[t];
    }
    for(t in 1:T)
        gamma[t] = softmax(loggamma[t]);
    } // forward-backward
    { // Viterbi algorithm
        real logp_zstar;
        int bpointer[T, K]; // backpointer to the most likely previous state on the most probable path
        real delta[T, K]; // max prob for the sequence up to t
        // that ends with an emission from state k
        for (j in 1:K)
            delta[1, K] = multi_normal_lpdf(eei[1] | Mu[][j], Sigma[][j]);
        for (t in 2:T) {
            for (j in 1:K) { // j = current (t)
                delta[t, j] = negative_infinity();
                for (i in 1:K) { // i = previous (t-1)
                    real logp;
                    logp = delta[t-1, i] + log(A[i, j]) + multi_normal_lpdf(eei[t] | Mu[][i], Sigma[][i]);
                    if (logp > delta[t, j]) {
                        bpointer[t, j] = i;
                        delta[t, j] = logp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        logp_zstar = max(delta[T]);
        for (j in 1:K)
            if (delta[T, j] == logp_zstar)
                zstar[T] = j;
        for (t in 1:(T - 1)) {
            zstar[T - t] = bpointer[T - t + 1, zstar[T - t + 1]];
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled using:

```
%%time
sm = pystan.StanModel(file='HMM_code.stan')
```

And fit using:

```
%%time
fit = sm.sampling(data=HMM_data, iter=1, thin = 1, verbose = True)
```

The error I'm getting is in the first line evaluating the multi_normal_pdf function, saying that "the LDLT_Factor of covariance parameter is not positive definite.  last conditional variance is 2.77556e-16"

Comment: I think the Dirichlet in the model LaTeX output should be Categorical to get a variate that can be used as an index like `l[t]` is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large covariance matrices can easily be numerically singular, even in this case where they are positive definite by construction. In order to avoid this problem and unnecessary computation, the usual thing to do in Stan is to declare the parameter as the Cholesky factor of a covariance or correlation matrix (in which case you also need to declare a positive vector of standard deviations in the parameters block).

In that case, you would call the `multi_normal_cholesky_lpdf` function, which conditions on a Cholesky factor of a covariance matrix rather than the covariance matrix itself, which in turn can be a `diag_pre_multiply` of a vector of standard deviations and the Cholesky factor of a correlation matrix. However, in that case, you would need to switch the priors from an inverse Wishart to a `lkj_corr_cholesky_lpdf` for the Cholesky factor of the correlation matrix and whatever you want (such as `exponential_lpdf`) for the standard deviations. This is all discussed in the Stan user manual.

Another [option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution#Conjugate_distribution) would be to integrate out the covariance matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and get back to you.